# How return only object contain string from XML/JSON URL

Tags: python, json, python-requests

If there anyone can help me get only string i need from parsing URL:

```
import requests 
import json

def get_stock(sku):
    params = {'ItemId': sku}
    base_url = 'http://10.0.0.25/api/GetSku?ItemId='
    response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
    json_parsed = json.loads(response.read)
     
    return json_parsed



    
print(get_stock(101025HRLONDON))
```

The output is:

```json
[
   {
        "ItemId": "101025HRLONDON",
        "Site": "12",
        "Warehouse": "17",
        "availablePhysical": 1.0
    },
    {
        "ItemId": "101025HRLONDON",
        "Site": "33",
        "Warehouse": "33",
        "availablePhysical": 1.0
    },
    {
        "ItemId": "101025HRLONDON",
        "Site": "12",
        "Warehouse": "34",
        "availablePhysical": 1.0
    },
    {
        "ItemId": "101025HRLONDON",
        "Site": "77",
        "Warehouse": "42",
        "availablePhysical": 1.0
    }
]
```

The code works well and returns all products stock by ItemID.

But my question is how I can return an only object that contains : `"Site":"12"`

Thank you!

Comment: hmm, you need to be more specific. there are multiple objects that share the ItemId `101025HRLONDON`. What is the criteria used to select the one with `Site: 12` for example? I suppose you could also get the first element of the list, which would satisfy the ask as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like the below

```
import requests 
from typing import List,Dict


def get_stock(sku:str,site_id:str)-> List[Dict]:
    base_url = 'http://10.0.0.25/api/GetSku?ItemId='
    response = requests.get(base_url, params={'ItemId': sku})
    if response.status_code == 200:
      return [item for item in response.json() if item['Site'] == site_id]
    else:
      return None
```

Comment: Thank you, just add last two lines to my code, and it's working well.

Comment: You've probably meant `base_url = 'http://10.0.0.25/api/GetSku'`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
return json_parsed
```

By:

```
if any(i['Site'] == '12' for i in json_parsed):
    return json_parsed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` the list using the key you want.
The function you've written is correct, you only need to manipulate the returned data.

```py
filtered_stocks = list(filter(lambda x: x['Site']=="12", get_stock("101025HRLONDON"))
print(filtered_stocks)
```